# Combine three different select statements into one (1)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three different tables, one containing folder information, one containing document information and one containing email information. I want to SELECT data from all three tables all at once in a SELECT query.

TABLE 1 (folder information):

```
CASE_ID | FOLDER_ID | PARENT_FOLDER_ID | FOLDER_NAME
123       C488785     null               casefolder 1
123       F488785     C488785            folder 1
123       SF48878     F488785            subfolder 1
```

TABLE 2 (document information):

```
CASE_ID | FOLDER_ID | DOCUMENT_ID | DOCUMENT_NAME | DOCUMENT_TYPE | IS_VISIBLE | ...
C488785 | SF488785  | d98765432   | document 1    | txt           | 1          | ...
```

TABLE 3 (email information):

```
CASE_ID | FOLDER_ID | EMAIL_ID | SUBJECT    | SENDER            | IS_VISIBLE | ...
C488785 | SF48878  | d12345678 | test mail  | sender@sender.nl  | 0          | ...
C488785 | F488785  | d67891234 | test mail2 | sender@sender.nl  | 0          | ...
```

See below the SQL statement I tried and which gives the expected result. However, I do not want to include this WITH in there. I prefer to not use this WITH.

```
WITH folder_information AS (
        SELECT T1.CASE_ID, T1.FOLDER_ID, T1.PARENT_FOLDER_ID, T1.FOLDER_NAME, T2.FOLDER_NAME "PARENT_FOLDER_NAME"
        FROM DB.FOLDER_DATA T1 LEFT JOIN DB.FOLDER_DATA  T2
        ON  (T1.PARENT_FOLDER_ID = T2.FOLDER_ID) 
        WHERE T1.CASE_ID=12345),

     files AS(
        SELECT CASE_ID, DOSSIER_ID, FOLDER_ID, DOCUMENT_ID, DOCUMENT_NAME, DOCUMENT_TYPE, UPLOADED_BY, UPLOADED_ON, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_ON, VERSION, IS_VISIBLE, IS_CHECKEDOUT, CHECKEDOUT_BY,
        NULL AS "EMAIL_ID", NULL AS "SUBJECT", NULL AS "SENDER", NULL AS "RECIPIENT", NULL AS "RECEIVED_DATE", NULL AS "ATTACHMENTS"
        FROM DB.DOCUMENT_DATA WHERE CASE_ID=12345

        UNION

        SELECT CASE_ID, DOSSIER_ID, FOLDER_ID, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, IS_VISIBLE, NULL, NULL, EMAIL_ID, SUBJECT, SENDER, RECIPIENT, RECEIVED_DATE, ATTACHMENTS
        FROM DB.EMAIL_DATA WHERE CASE_ID=12345)

SELECT T1.CASE_ID, T1.DOSSIER_ID, T1.FOLDER_ID, T1.DOCUMENT_ID, T1.DOCUMENT_NAME, T1.DOCUMENT_TYPE, T1.UPLOADED_BY, T1.UPLOADED_ON, T1.MODIFIED_BY, T1.MODIFIED_ON, T1.VERSION, T1.IS_VISIBLE, T1.IS_CHECKEDOUT, T1.CHECKEDOUT_BY,
T1.EMAIL_ID, T1.SUBJECT, T1.SENDER, T1.RECIPIENT, T1.RECEIVED_DATE, T1.ATTACHMENTS ,T2.FOLDER_NAME, T2.PARENT_FOLDER_NAME
FROM files T1, folder_information T2
WHERE T1.CASE_ID = T2.CASE_ID AND T1.FOLDER_ID = T2.FOLDER_ID
```

The above code result in the following, and this is how I expect the result to be:

```
RESULT TABLE 1 (folder information):
CASE_ID | FOLDER_ID | DOCUMENT_ID | DOCUMENT_NAME | ... | EMAIL_ID | SUBJECT | ... | FOLDER_NAME | PARENT_FOLDER_NAME

C488785 | SF48878 | d98765432 | document 1 | ... | null | null | ... | subfolder 1 | folder 1
C488785 | SF48878 | null | null | ... | d12345678 | test mail  | ... | subfolder 1 | folder 1
C488785 | F488785 | null | null | ... | d67891234 | test mail2 | ... | folder 1    | casefolder 1
```

REMARK: For the ease of reading I replaced some of the columns by the dots (...)

Comment: Why don't you want to use `WITH`? You seem to have a working query here.

Comment: Software where I use the statement is not supporting that .. :(

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: The DB I use Oracle

Comment: Hello Nick, please take a couple of minutes to come up with a simple example that illustrates your problem. Post the statements to create the tables, insert the sample rows and the sql with the WITH clause you want to see converted to a statement without the WITH clause. You'll have an answer in minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just move subqueries to `from` part

```
SELECT T1.CASE_ID, T1.DOSSIER_ID, T1.FOLDER_ID, T1.DOCUMENT_ID, T1.DOCUMENT_NAME, T1.DOCUMENT_TYPE, T1.UPLOADED_BY, T1.UPLOADED_ON, T1.MODIFIED_BY, T1.MODIFIED_ON, T1.VERSION, T1.IS_VISIBLE, T1.IS_CHECKEDOUT, T1.CHECKEDOUT_BY,
T1.EMAIL_ID, T1.SUBJECT, T1.SENDER, T1.RECIPIENT, T1.RECEIVED_DATE, T1.ATTACHMENTS ,T2.FOLDER_NAME, T2.PARENT_FOLDER_NAME
FROM 
(
        SELECT CASE_ID, DOSSIER_ID, FOLDER_ID, DOCUMENT_ID, DOCUMENT_NAME, DOCUMENT_TYPE, UPLOADED_BY, UPLOADED_ON, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_ON, VERSION, IS_VISIBLE, IS_CHECKEDOUT, CHECKEDOUT_BY,
        NULL AS "EMAIL_ID", NULL AS "SUBJECT", NULL AS "SENDER", NULL AS "RECIPIENT", NULL AS "RECEIVED_DATE", NULL AS "ATTACHMENTS"
        FROM DB.DOCUMENT_DATA WHERE CASE_ID=12345

        UNION

        SELECT CASE_ID, DOSSIER_ID, FOLDER_ID, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, IS_VISIBLE, NULL, NULL, EMAIL_ID, SUBJECT, SENDER, RECIPIENT, RECEIVED_DATE, ATTACHMENTS
        FROM DB.EMAIL_DATA WHERE CASE_ID=12345
) T1, 
(
        SELECT T1.CASE_ID, T1.FOLDER_ID, T1.PARENT_FOLDER_ID, T1.FOLDER_NAME, T2.FOLDER_NAME "PARENT_FOLDER_NAME"
        FROM DB.FOLDER_DATA T1 LEFT JOIN DB.FOLDER_DATA  T2
        ON  (T1.PARENT_FOLDER_ID = T2.FOLDER_ID) 
        WHERE T1.CASE_ID=12345
) T2
WHERE T1.CASE_ID = T2.CASE_ID AND T1.FOLDER_ID = T2.FOLDER_ID
```